# Present one view in landscape mode in an otherwise portrait mode app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an application (iPhone only) that is portrait-only, but with one exception, a view that must be displayed in landscape mode.

I have implemented the technique described in the accepted answer in [How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift#41811798), albeit in Objective-C.

Since I've overridden the -lockOrientation methods in -viewWillAppear and -viewWillDisappear of the landscape view controller, I don't undertand why I see rotation occur after the view appears; I would have thought that would occur before the view appears.

When my presented landscape view is overlaid by a presented portrait view, the portrait view starts out as landscape (because it's presented over a landscape view before rotation), but the rotated view has only the height it had in landscape mode.

When the portrait view is dismissed, the first, landscape view has now rotated to portrait mode, even though I've also implemented -supportedInterfaceOrientations and -preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation for landscape mode. This has been noted in [UIViewController orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125672/uiviewcontroller-orientations), but there didn't appear to be any working solutions posted there.

Both view controllers, the landscape and the portrait that overlays it, are presented rather than pushed.

Also, the only flag set in the project's Info.plist is Portrait. The full-screen flag is *not* set.

In short, it's a hot mess just trying to make one exception to view orientation in my app.

Any clues to solving the behavior I've described would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, check [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928057/only-one-view-landscape-mode)

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you so much for replying.